# Make native C++ Code to a Blueprint in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm new at UE4, so if I do something horrible wrong, tell it to me. I'm happy about everything I can learn

The question: is it Possible to make a Blueprint out of a normal C++ class? It should - with the right includes -
because I made a C++ class "Graph" for the University, and I like to implement it in to a game as base of a Skill-Tree.
It should be "UCLASS(Blueprintable)" to make it simple and clear to read. And also Native, course I do the Garbage collection for the System :)

The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<class T>
class Graph
{


public:
    T element;
    std::list<Graph<T>*> childs;
    std::list<Graph<T>*> parents;
    Graph();
    Graph(T);
    ~Graph();
    Graph<T>* makeNewChild(T);
    bool pushChildtoParent(Graph<T>*);
    Graph<T>* makeNewChild(Graph<T>*);
    bool deleteChild(Graph<T>*);
    bool makeParent(Graph<T>*);
    T getElement();
    bool leaf;
};

template<class T>
Graph<T>::Graph()
{
    leaf = true;
    element = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
Graph<T>::Graph(T element) : element(element)
{
    leaf = true;
}

template<class T>
Graph<T>::~Graph()
{
    if(!leaf)
        {
            for (auto it = childs.begin(); it != childs.end();)
            {
                // wenn das kind nicht mehrere Väter hat, denen ich es nicht weg nehmen will
                if ((**it).parents.size()<2)
                {
                     delete *it ++;
                }
                else{
                    (**it).parents.remove(this);
                    it ++;
                }
            }
        }
    if (!(*this).parents.empty())
    {
         for (auto it = parents.begin(); it != parents.end(); it++)
        {
            //alle Väter vergessen dieses Kind, damit es ohne folgen beseitigt werden kann
            (**it).deleteChild(this);
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
T Graph<T>::getElement()
{
    return (*this).element;
}

template<class T>
bool Graph<T>::deleteChild(Graph<T>* tokill)
{
    for (auto it = childs.begin(); it != childs.end(); it++)
    {
        if( (*it)==tokill){
            childs.erase(it);
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Error code hier einfügen
    std::cout<<"Leider dieses Kind nicht gefunden. Error main2.h at line 61"<<std::endl;
    return false;
}

//eingane der zu setzende Vater. Wenn setzen des Vaters gelingt, wird er in die Liste der Väter aufgenommen

template<class T>
bool Graph<T>::makeParent (Graph<T>* newParent){
    if ((*newParent).pushChildtoParent(this)){
        parents.push_back(newParent);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //Error code hier einfügen
        std::cout<<"das Erzeugen dieses Kindes bei dem Vater war nicht möglich. Error main2.h at line 76"<<std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

template<class T>
bool Graph<T>::pushChildtoParent(Graph<T>* inTree){
    childs.push_back(inTree);
    leaf = false;
    return true;
}

template<class T>
Graph<T>* Graph<T>::makeNewChild(T inValue)
{
    Graph<T>* contain = new Graph<T>(inValue);
    childs.push_back(contain);
    (*contain).parents.push_back(this);
    leaf = false;
    return contain;
}

template<class T>
Graph<T>* Graph<T>::makeNewChild(Graph<T>* inTree)
{
    childs.push_back(inTree);
    (*inTree).parents.push_back(this);
    leaf = false;
    return inTree;
}
```

Or should I rewrite it, with out the Template?
course I'm sure, the type T will be " Skill* "

I think making on this point Blueprints will make the effort for the after develop balancing from skills and so on better, faster and easy to handle.

It would be nice if you can help me on this point.

Comment: I would like to make a UCLASS(Blueprintable) out of the class Graph, so I can call in a Blueprint "makeNewChild" and don´t have to code the Hole Skill-Tree in C++ code ...
This would be a bloody mess to get a Overview about the hole Skill-Tree

Ore what do you mean withe "use it"?

Comment: Ah, I just realized that blueprints are an Unreal thing. Then I'm out, sorry.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the easiest and most robust way to use "foreign" c++ code in UE4 is to create some proxy UCLASS that uses your custom c++ class and can itself be called by blueprints. The reason for that is that UE4 has its own "way" of doing things in C++, e.g. you should use 'TArray' instead of 'list' and 'UE_Log' instead of 'stdout'.

So I would suggest the following:

- Create a new C++ class which extends UObject (or AActor if you want to place it in the level):

[image: Create new c++ class]

- include your custom graph in the new class
- Add UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, ...) annotated methods to your class that call and manipulate the graph (also converting to and from UE4 and raw C++ types if necessary)
- (Optional) Create a new blueprint that extends your new C++ class to add functions via the blueprint editor
- Now you can use your new class in other blueprints